# Is there a full-stack cron alternative?

Tags: open-source, library, scheduling, planning, job-scheduler

is there a **Cron** open source alternative out there which does come with additional **monitoring** and **logging** capabilities, as well as **timezone awareness**?

PS: **Apache Airflow** is at the moment not a cron alternative due to issues with high availability, fast execution and inflexible/non-dynamic job scheduling ([1](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10449), [2](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10194))

Comment: What do you understand on "stack" here? Recently the word "stack" started to be used for *anything*, like "network stack", "xy software stack", but I think you now randomly picked out some extra functionality to the crond and collected them together into the umbrella term "full-stack".

Comment: What do you want to monitor? What do you want to log? (Btw, I did not vote or flag your post, because I see some chance that it is still useful.)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica The terminology "stack" is nowadays referred to the scope of a to the fullest extend functional entity. This entity can be software, software developer, hardware etc. If one uses the term full-stack on software, like I did, this would mean a piece of software, which offers the ability to cover all (or a huge amount) of use cases relevant in a particular area of software use cases.

Comment: So when I am asking of a full-stack cron alternative, this would mean, a piece of alternative software, which covers all cron use cases and even more. I think the understanding of the terminology is quite clear to most of the people within the domain.

Comment: And to those who it is not, the question elaborates the semantic of the question title completely.

Comment: Stack "scope of a to the fullest extend functional entity" <- this is meaningless, gibberish. Typical case as a crap terminology was invented because it sounds well. Stack is a packed data structure with a LIFO constraint.

Comment: If you want to talk about linguistic concepts, I am totally happy to discuss this with you in a different place, since I am a Msc computational linguist. And I could tell you how the semantics of a former context here, the definition of a data structure, could become broader and slipped into a different scope. But this does not have anything to do with the question I asked. I think the question is clear and structured.

Comment: If your use case is specific for Java, I could suggest the [quarz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). It is called also as "Quarz Enterprise Job Scheduler". What is the "enterprise" in a .jar file, uhmm, this is what my previous comments about :-) But your question suggests that you likely want more a boosted crond in a linux shell environment?

Comment: Thank you for the information on the quarz scheduler, I will have a look into it. It somehow seems, that besides non open source enterprise solutions, there is really a lack of a more sophisticated scheduling open source software. In the end it would be great to have monitoring and logging capabilities covered with a fast an accurate execution. Especially the last point is what I really miss within the apache airflow project.

Comment: Quartz is open source. But it is a jar file, essentially it is a Java library. The "enterprise" string in its name is a bullshit terminology. If you have a Java program and you want it to execute tasks periodically, on parallel threads, it is useful. For any other tasks, it is not. How about writing a wrapper script in bash? Btw, in Airflow I see some essential problems: 1. it is written in Python. Python programs are mostly crap.

Comment: 2. *"Out of the box, Airflow uses a sqlite database, which you should outgrow fairly quickly since no parallelization is possible using this database backend."* These are 3 huge red flags. If a program uses an SQL DB and you have no option to choose its database type, then this program is a crap. Second, SQLite is pretty well multithreaded long, long ago. Instead, where multithreading is disfunctional, is the python (as everything). On these reasons, I would stop investigating this task on the spot. Third red flag is this: that they explain, how their thing works, is not "out of the box".